# Grid to display columns as per the specified height using bootstrap in React app

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am displaying a mega menu dynamically and for this I want to create a grid as per the requirement. Here the some points to consider:

1. I want to display data in columns and extra column will automatically get 
   added if data increases.
2. Height of the mega menu will be fixed e.g. 300px and column data will get 
   added as per the mega menu height and column content. (If that much of 
   space not available then that div will create another column automatically)
3. One column might contain multiple small size columns.
4. Data will get displayed in columns automatically using json.

I tried row column structure of bootstrap, but data get displayed horizontally as per the row and I want data vertically as per the columns.

I'm creating like this structure dynamically using .map on array

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-md-4"></div>
  <div className="col-md-4"></div>
  <div className="col-md-4"></div>
  <div className="col-md-4"></div>
  <div className="col-md-4"></div>
  <div className="col-md-4"></div>
  <div className="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

For more details:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the flexbox, will help you to get result. Here is the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33204824)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, bootstrap expects you to divide your layout into 12 columns. Your current DOM uses 28 columns (4 * 7). It'll probably behave weirdly in the UI.

You just need to think in terms of rows and columns, the way bootstrap does. Here is a sample structure trying to mimic your screenshot. You need to alter the `col-md-*` as per your needs.

```css
div {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2
      <div class="row">1</div>
      <div class="row">2</div>
      <div class="row">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3
      <div class="row">1</div>
      <div class="row">2</div>
      <div class="row">3</div>
      <div class="row">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but problem is that I am not doing this code manually. I'm forming this in the .map function of array and I need to decide column content as per the height of the mega menu.

Comment: Then please share the code relevant to your problem.